# Plot surface dividing 3d data by value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, surface

I have a 3d dataset, where each sample has 3 coordinates (x,y,z) and a value either 0 or 1. I want to plot a surface which divides the points with value 1 from the points with value 0. For example, let's say that all the points with x,y and z grater than zero have value 1, while all other points have value 0. But in my problem, I don't know the analytical expression that divides the two categories. What would the best way to draw such surface in Python?

Comment: add some test data and expected visualisation output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SVC (Support Vector Classifier). It gives you the decision boudaries for the classed data. Scikit learn has an API for SVC -
 [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)